# Using MessagingCenter in UWP's BackgroundTask

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms

I want use **Background Task** to send data to UWP App so i think about **MessagingCenter**. I have created a **Portable Library** which is referenced by **UWP App** and **Runtime Component**,it contains an empty class named **ProgressMessage**.
While Background Task is running, data is sent to App by MessagingCenter.Send but nothing was happen in App.

[run method in RuntimeComponent]

```
            ProgressMessage _progressMessage = new ProgressMessage();
            //Send message to MessagingCenter
            MessagingCenter.Send<ProgressMessage, decimal>(_progressMessage, "Value", value);
```

[MainPage]

```
public MainPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        BindingContext = this;
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ProgressMessage, decimal>(this, "Value", (message, value) =>
           {
               Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => {
                   this.Value = value;
                   Debug.WriteLine("Value is " + value.ToString());
               });
           });
    }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin, but, in my understanding, the messaging center is designed for in-process messaging - like as between view models.
Basically, UWP Background task is running with their own process - separated from the main app. This means you should have inter-process messaging model.

Comment: u r right. Now i use BackgroundTaskProgressEventHandler to pass value.